# RabbitMQ requires a PC restart or service restart to send messges

Tags: c#, service, rabbitmq, erlang

RabbitMQ seems to be in a weird state. We install RabbitMQ and Erlang, one of its pre requsite in our application. When trying to send message in the queue, it throws us exceptions thus the queue is just filling up. We need to either reboot the PC or restart the RabbitMQ server to start sending the message again.

Note - I don't have any logs and know what is exact exception as this happened in our during installation at customer site ad we have no access to them. This issue was found happening only at customers site in many of the platforms.

I require suggestions as to what may cause such use case. Is there a way i can test for weird state of rabbitmq and restart them in such use case from code. Or any generic way to handle from code ?